# Difference in CTE using SQLite3 and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I'm practicing SQL in Jupyter Notebook. I use sqlaclhemy and psycopg2 libs for practicing PostgreSQL syntax (using  ElephantSQL) and sqlite3 lib for local db.

I have a request:

```
sql = '''

with medium_credits as (
    select t.credit_amount from german_credit t
    where t.credit_amount > 1000 and t.credit_amount < 3000
    group by t.credit_amount),
    
medium_credits_info as (
    select * from german_credit t
    where t.credit_amount in medium_credits)
    

select t.purpose, t.housing, count(1) as count 
from medium_credits_info t
    
group by t.purpose, t.housing
        
'''
```

Running this request using `pd.read_sql(sql,connection)`, where connection is object created with sqlite3 - it goes great.

When I try to try it in Postgres-like system using `pd.read_sql(sql,engine)`, where engine is object created with sqlalchemy, it throws a ProgrammingError:

```
ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near "medium_credits"
LINE 14:     where t.credit_amount in medium_credits)
```

I guess, Postgres doesn't let you use values from CTE-created table directly this way.

Is there any option I could run this code without an error?

PS: local and elephantsql databases are identical

Comment: Well, `where t.credit_amount in medium_credits`  is invalid (standard) SQL and rightfully rejected by Postgres. The `IN` operator does not allow a table reference on the right hand side. It should be: `where t.credit_amount in (select credit_amount from medium_credits)`

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
with medium_credits as (
    select t.credit_amount from german_credit t
    where t.credit_amount > 1000 and t.credit_amount < 3000
    group by t.credit_amount),
    
medium_credits_info as (
    SELECT * 
      FROM german_credit t
     INNER JOIN medium_credits m
        ON m.credit_amount = t.credit_amount)
```